# Обособление развёрнутых определений

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "грехи" в предложении "Не стоит упрекать за грехи частично искоренённые и частично трансформировавшиеся в добродетели"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

Здесь нужно смотреть на логическое ударение. В данном примере оно падает на существительное (*грехи*). Если оно падает на определение (стоящее после существительного), запятая не ставится. Ещё в таких случаях при изъятии определения нарушается смысл и не звучит. А "*Не стоит упрекать за грехи*" — вполне звучит.

Розенталь:
Не обособляются распространенные определения, стоящие после существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении:
*Марья Дмитриевна приняла вид достОйный и несколько обиженный* — сочетание слов *приняла вид* не имеет смысла.
*Чернышевский создал произведение в высшей степени оригинАльное и чрезвычайно замечательное.

Вы выбрали судью довольно стрОгого.

Вернер — человек замечАтельный по многим причинам.

Попытки писать просто приводили к результатам печАльным и смешным* — без последующих двух определений существительное не выражает нужного понятия.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108